# localhost mysql issue with EXISTS

Tags: mysql, xampp

it seems mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev bounded with XAMPP has issue with `EXISTS` . I'm trying to run [this query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
  SELECT column1 FROM t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2);
```

but it doesn't run and output below errors:

> Static analysis:
>
> 2 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Unrecognized keyword. (near "EXISTS" at position 38)
>    Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 45)
>
> SQL query: Documentation
>
> SELECT column1 FROM t1 WHERE EXISTS ( LIMIT 0, 25
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>   1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

EDIT: issue resolved by wrapping `EXISTS` statement into `()` :

```
 SELECT column1 FROM t1 WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2));
```

but it is not indicated in official [mysql documentaion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) 
is it only a documentation syntax error?

Comment: And this is the actual query?!?

Comment: Is it MySQL or MariaDB now?

Comment: but as-is it's a nonsense query. If there is any data at all in t2 then all rows of t1 are returned. There is no cross-table correlation e.g. SELECT column1 FROM t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2 `where t1.column = t2.column`);