# Need help in nested sql queries

Tags: sql, subquery

Please help me with this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM documents 
WHERE doc_id <> (SELECT doc_id 
                 FROM doc_submitted 
                 WHERE student_IDNUM = 131009685)
```

What I want is to get all documents that are not in the `doc_submitted`.

Comment: I will prefer the `NOT EXISTS` solution by Gordan it is faster than the other methods atleast in `SQL SERVER`. Also it handles `NULL` values in sub-query. `NOT IN` fails when the `sub-query` returns any `NULL` values

Comment: Here is a good article compares the performance between all the possible methods. [Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally recommend `NOT EXISTS` over `NOT IN`, because `NOT IN` returns zero rows if even one row in the subquery has a `NULL` value:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM documents d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM doc_submitted ds
                  WHERE ds.doc_id = d.docid AND ds.student_IDNUM = 131009685
                 )
```

Comment: im using xampp and this query contains 3 error. why is that? while this one works "SELECT * FROM documents WHERE doc_id NOT IN 
(
     SELECT doc_id FROM doc_submitted WHERE student_IDNUM = 131009685
)"

Comment: @n4mi - check the latest query

Comment: i fixed the typo by the way

Comment: @n4mi - I dont know about `xampp`  but that is a valid `SQL`

Comment: @Gordon - i guess ill just have to settle for the "NOT IN" for now. Thanks anyways.

"no need to move it to anywhere :D"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100281/localhost-mysql-issue-with-exists

thank you stackoverflow. i got the answer and now it is working perfectly.

"SELECT d.*
FROM documents d
WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM doc_submitted ds
                  WHERE ds.doc_id = d.doc_id AND ds.student_IDNUM = 131009685
                 ))"

Answer (score 1):

You can use left join also for omitting the unwanted records.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM documents a
  LEFT JOIN  doc_submitted b ON   a.doc_id=b.doc_id AND b.student_IDNUM = 131009685 
WHERE b. doc_id IS null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **NOT IN**:

NOT IN will **Omit** records from main query which are **available** in sub query.

```
SELECT * FROM documents WHERE doc_id NOT IN 
(
     SELECT doc_id FROM doc_submitted WHERE student_IDNUM = 131009685
)
```

Comment: Welcome, I agree with @Gordon

Answer (score 0):

It's known as an anti-join and like many relational operators there is no direct equivalent in SQL. Instead we must choose from a variety of workarounds e.g. here's one:

```
SELECT doc_id 
  FROM documents 
EXCEPT
SELECT doc_id 
  FROM doc_submitted 
 WHERE student_IDNUM = 131009685
```